# Making a dice roller for D&D; why is Ruby giving me a NameError?

Tags: ruby, nameerror

I'm very new to coding and have been trying to improve upon a dice roller for D&D that I found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/185121/dice-roller-in-ruby-mainly-for-dd). I have a variable that determines if the roll's modifier is positive or negative, but for some reason Ruby is giving me a NameError (undefined local variable or method `pos_or_neg' for main:Object). Would also appreciate general advice for making my code better.

```
def roll(amount = 0, sides = 0)
  #For every die(amount), randomly generate a result limited to sides, then add all results together.
  amount.to_i.times.sum { |t| rand(1..sides.to_i) }
end

puts "Gimme some dice to roll! (e.g. 2d4, 1d12-1, etc.)"
loop do
  input = gets.chomp.to_s

  abort("May your rolls be ever natural.") if input == "exit"
  next puts "Please specify the number of dice!" if input.start_with?("d")

  #Check if modifier is positive or negative.
  pos_or_neg == true if input.include? "+"; pos_or_neg == false if input.include? "-"

  #Replace everything but numbers with spaces in input, then split.
  amount, sides, mod = input.tr("^0-9", " ").split

  #Calculate final result using pos_or_neg to determine modifier.
  pos_or_neg == true ? fin = roll(amount, sides) + mod.to_i : roll(amount, sides) - mod.to_i
  puts fin

end
```

I apologize if this kind of thing is asked often.

Comment: Hi, `pos_or_neg == true` looks like you was trying to do `pos_or_neg = true` here in first case

Comment: Try not to stack multiple Ruby statements with `;`. One of the best things about Ruby is how easy it is to read and that defeats the purpose. You also don't need to do logical comparisons like `x == true` if `x` is a boolean value, just do `x`.

Comment: Although they might be a bit dizzying to pick up on, this sort of problem lends itself to using regular expressions: `/\A(\d+)d(\d+)(?:[\-\+]?\d})\z/` will match strings of the form `NdN+/-N` and breaks out the parts into three distinct values you can operate on.

Comment: Thanks Yurii and tadman. I will look into regular expressions. They seem like a better way of going about things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Yurii said in the comment to your question, you are comparing (`==`) instead of assigning the value (`=`).

But also, if there's neither '+' nor '-' in `input` then `pos_or_neg` won't be defined. You could change the line:

```
 pos_or_neg == true if input.include? "+"; pos_or_neg == false if input.include? "-"
```

with:

```
 pos_or_neg = !input.include?('-')
```

(assuming that the case when there's neither '+' nor '-' is taken as positive)

And (I think) it would be more readable if you change this line:

```
pos_or_neg == true ? fin = roll(amount, sides) + mod.to_i : roll(amount, sides) - mod.to_i
```

with

```
  fin = roll(amount, sides) + mod.to_i * (pos_or_neg ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice! I didn't really know how to deal with situations when there is no modifier. I still don't understand why `fin` isn't being defined when `pos_or_neg` is false.

Comment: @Richard I was not aware the last assigment was valid the way you did it, I thought it was an error. Updated my answer. Sorry!